# Applgrid makefile (undefined reference)

Tags: compilation, makefile, g++

I've a question that could be naive for the experienced users, but I'm kinda stuck. I'm trying to get ApplGrid code working (https://applgrid.hepforge.org/index.htm), so I wish to run the provided examples.

As far as I've understood, the dependencies are ROOT (root.cern.ch) and LHAPDF libraries (lhapdf.hepforge.org/index.html), which work well on my machine.
The aforementioned examples were build to work with an older version of LHAPDF, so I had to change the name of an invoked method.
When I try to make, I get an error regarding the undefined reference of that function, but if I isolate that instruction and execute with

```
g++ extract.cxx `lhapdf-config --cflags --ldflags`
```

it works like a charm.

The output of the config command is:

> -I/home/matteo/software/gcc-4.7/lhapdf/install/include -I/home/matteo/software/gcc-4.7/boost/install/include -L/home/matteo/software/gcc-4.7/lhapdf/install/lib -lLHAPDF

If I remove the "LHAPDF-related commands" from the original cxx file I can run "make" without any problem.

As a final test, I've tried to isolate the "applgrid related code" and try to compile with:

```
g++ extract_2.cxx `applgrid-config --cxxflags --ldfflags`
```

but I get an undefined reference error.

The output of the config command is:

> -I/home/matteo/software/gcc-4.7/applgrid/install/include -pthread -m64 -I/home/matteo/software/gcc-4.7/root/install/include -L/home/matteo/software/gcc-4.7/applgrid/install/lib -lfAPPLgrid -lAPPLgrid -m64 -L/home/matteo/software/gcc-4.7/root/install/lib -lCore -lCint -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lTree -lRint -lPostscript -lMatrix -lPhysics -lMathCore -lThread -pthread -lm -ldl -rdynamic -L/home/matteo/software/gcc-4.7/hoppet/install/lib -lhoppet_v1

the content of the makefile is the following:

```
CXX = g++
F77 = gfortran

FFLAGS   += -O3 -fPIC
CXXFLAGS += -O3 -fPIC

# root
ROOTINCS = $(shell root-config --cflags)
ROOTLIBS = $(shell root-config --glibs)
ROOTARCH = $(findstring -m64, $(ROOTINCS) )

#LHAPDF
LHAPDFINCS = $(shell lhapdf-config --cflags)
LHAPDFDIR  = $(shell lhapdf-config --libdir)
LHAPDFLIBS = $(shell lhapdf-config --libs)

# applgrid
APPLCXXFLAGS = $(shell applgrid-config --cxxflags)
APPLCLIBS    = $(shell applgrid-config --ldcflags)
APPLFLIBS    = $(shell applgrid-config --ldflags)

# hoppet
HOPPETLIBS =  $(shell hoppet-config --libs)

# get the fotran runtime library for linking fortran

FRTLLIB = $(shell gfortran $(CXXFLAGS) -print-file-name=libgfortran.a)
FRTLIB  = -L$(subst /libgfortran.a, ,$(FRTLLIB) ) -lgfortran

# now set up the compile and link flags and libs
CXXFLAGS += $(ROOTARCH) $(ROOTINCS) $(APPLCXXFLAGS) $(LHAPDFINCS)
LDFLAGS  += $(ROOTARCH)
FFLAGS   += $(ROOTARCH)

CLIBS += $(ROOTLIBS) $(LHAPDFLIBS) $(HOPPETLIBS) $(APPLCLIBS)
FLIBS += $(ROOTLIBS) $(LHAPDFLIBS) $(HOPPETLIBS) $(APPLFLIBS) $(APPLCLIBS) $(FRTLIB)

install : all
all : stand fnlo fstand getdata

stand: stand.o
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(CLIBS)


fstand: fstand.o fmain.o
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ fstand.o fmain.o $(FLIBS)


% : %.o
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(CLIBS)

fnlo: fnmain.o
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@  $<  $(CLIBS)


.SUFFIXES : .cxx .o .f .c

.f.o :
        $(F77) $(FFLAGS)   -c $<

.cxx.o:  
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<


#########################################################
#  just type make getdata and it will download all
#  the required data for these examples
#########################################################

.PRECIOUS : fnlodata appldata

getdata : getfnlodata getappldata

getfnlodata: fnl0004.tab
fnl0004.tab:
        @ echo "\n************************\ndownloading fastnlo data\n************************\n"
        (curl http://fastnlo.hepforge.org/code/src/fnl0004.tab.gz | gunzip > fnl0004.tab )

getappldata: atlas-incljets-arxiv-1009.5908v2
atlas-incljets-arxiv-1009.5908v2:
        @ echo "\n*************************************\n downloading atlas inclusive jet data\n***********************************\n"
        (curl http://www.hepforge.org/archive/applgrid/atlas-incljets-arxiv-1009.5908v2.tgz | tar -xzf - )

clean:
        rm -rf ./.libs ./.obj *.lo *.o *.la stand fnlo fstand *~
```

while the other files in the directory are the following:

fmain.cxx

```
extern "C" void fstand_();

int main() { 
  fstand_();
  return 0
```

fnmain.cxx

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "appl_grid/fastnlo.h"

#include "TFile.h"
#include "TH1D.h"


// lhapdf routines
#include "LHAPDF/LHAPDF.h"
extern "C" void evolvepdf_(const double& , const double& , double* );
extern "C" double alphaspdf_(const double& Q);



int main(int argc, char** argv) { 

  if ( argc<2 ) { 
    std::cerr << "usage: fnlo fastnlogrid.tab" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  std::cout << "set up lhapdf..." << std::endl;

  const std::string _pdfname = "cteq6mE.LHgrid";  
  int iset = 0;
  LHAPDF::initPDFSet( _pdfname, iset );

  // don't need to hard code, can use a runtime parameter...
  std::string gridname = argv[1];
  // std::string gridname = "fnt1007midp.tab";
  // std::string gridname = "fnt1008midp.tab";
  // std::string gridname = "fnt2004.tab";
  // std::string gridname = "fnl2004.tab";

  fastnlo f( gridname );

  std::vector<appl::grid*> g = f.grids(); 

  //  g.push_back( new appl::grid("atlas-incljets04-eta1.root") );

  /// histograms and file for seeing the results
  std::vector<TH1D*> hc(g.size());
  std::string foutname = "appl.root";
  TFile fout( foutname.c_str(),"recreate");

  for ( int i=0 ; i<g.size() ; i++ ) { 

    // trim the grids (not actually needed, done in 
    // the fastnlo constructor
    g[i]->trim();

    char hname[64];
    sprintf(hname, "hist%02d", i);

    /// optionally print out the grid documentation  
    std::cout << "\n" << g[i]->getDocumentation() << std::endl;

    /// perform the convolution
    hc[i] = g[i]->convolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ );
    hc[i]->SetName(hname);
    hc[i]->SetDirectory(&fout);
    hc[i]->Write();

    /// print out the results
    for ( int j=1 ; j<=hc[i]->GetNbinsX() ; j++ ) { 
      std::cout << "xsec(" << j-1 << ")=" << hc[i]->GetBinContent(j) << std::endl;
    }

  }

  std::cout << "writing file " << foutname << std::endl; 
  fout.Close();

  return 0;
}

}
```

fstand.f

```
C----------------------------------------------------------
C     dummy routines that call  the pdf and alphas routines
C     this example, they just call the lhapdf routine
C     for apdf fit, call your own routines 
C----------------------------------------------------------
      double precision function fnalphas(Q)
      double precision Q      
      double precision alphaspdf
      fnalphas = alphaspdf(Q)
      return
      end

      subroutine fnpdf(x, Q, xf)
      double precision x, Q      
      double precision xf(13)
      call evolvePDF(x, Q, xf)
      return
      end
C----------------------------------------------------------
```

stand.cxx

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "appl_grid/appl_grid.h"
#include "appl_grid/appl_timer.h"

#include "TH1D.h"
#include "TPad.h"


// lhapdf routines
#include "LHAPDF/LHAPDF.h"
extern "C" void evolvepdf_(const double& , const double& , double* ); 
extern "C" double alphaspdf_(const double& Q);



int main(int argc, char** argv) { 



  // use a default atlas inclusive grid
  std::string gridname = "atlas-incljets04-eta1.root";

  if ( argc>1 ) gridname = argv[1];

  std::cout << "reading grid " << gridname << std::endl; 

  // get name of grid from user and create from grid file
  appl::grid g(gridname);

  g.trim(); // trim away uneeded memory

  /// print the grid documentation     
  std::cout << g.getDocumentation() << std::endl; 







  // initialise lhapdf

  std::cout << "setting up lhapdf" << std::endl; 

  // const std::string _pdfname = "cteq6mE.LHgrid";  
  const std::string _pdfname = "CT10.LHgrid";      
  int iset = 0;

  LHAPDF::initPDFSet( _pdfname, iset );
  // initpdfset_(_pdfname.c_str());
  // initpdf_( iset );






  // do the convolution into a vector
  std::cout << "doing standalone convolution" << std::endl; 

  //  struct timeval atimer = appl_timer_start(); 

  std::vector<double>  xsec = g.vconvolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 

  //  double atime = appl_timer_stop(atimer); 
  //  std::cout << "time " << atime << " ms" << std::endl;

  for ( int i=0 ; i<xsec.size() ; i++ ) std::cout << "xsec[" << i << "]\t= " << xsec[i] << std::endl;  





  // do the convolution into a TH1D

  //  atimer = appl_timer_start(); 
  TH1D*  hxsec = g.convolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 
  //  atime = appl_timer_stop(atimer); 
  //  std::cout << "time " << atime << " ms" << std::endl;

  hxsec->SetLineColor(kRed);
  hxsec->SetMarkerColor(kRed);
  hxsec->SetMarkerStyle(20);
  hxsec->DrawCopy();
  gPad->SetLogy(true);

  gPad->Print("xsec.pdf");



  return 0;
}
```

stand-full.cxx

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "appl_grid/appl_grid.h"
#include "appl_grid/appl_timer.h"

#include "TH1D.h"
#include "TPad.h"


// lhapdf routines
#include "LHAPDF/LHAPDF.h"
extern "C" void evolvepdf_(const double& , const double& , double* ); 
extern "C" double alphaspdf_(const double& Q);



int main(int argc, char** argv) { 

  // use a default atlas inclusive grid
  std::string gridname = "atlas-incljets04-eta1.root";

  if ( argc>1 ) gridname = argv[1];

  std::cout << "reading grid " << gridname << std::endl; 

  // get name of grid from user and create from grid file
  appl::grid g(gridname);

  g.trim(); // trim away uneeded memory

  std::cout << "setting up lhapdf" << std::endl; 

  // initialise lhapdf

  //  const std::string _pdfname = "cteq6mE.LHgrid";  
  const std::string _pdfname = "CT10.LHgrid";  
  int iset = 0;

  LHAPDF::initPDFSet( _pdfname, iset );
  // initpdfset_(_pdfname.c_str());
  // initpdf_( iset );

  // do the convolution into a vector
  std::cout << "doing standalone convolution" << std::endl; 
  std::cout << g.getDocumentation() << std::endl; 


  struct timeval atimer = appl_timer_start(); 

  std::vector<double>  xsec = g.vconvolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 

  double atime = appl_timer_stop(atimer); 

  const int Nsubproc = g.subProcesses();

  std::cout << "time : " << atime << " ms\tNsubproc : " << Nsubproc << std::endl;

  std::vector<std::vector<double> >  xsb(Nsubproc);

  for ( int i=0 ; i<Nsubproc ; i++ ) { 
    xsb[i] = g.vconvolute( i, evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 
  }


  // print results
  for ( int i=0 ; i<xsec.size() ; i++ ) { 
    std::cout << "xsec(" << i << ")=" << xsec[i] << std::endl;
  }

  for ( int i=0 ; i<Nsubproc ; i++ ) { 
    std::cout << "subproc: " << i << std::endl;
    for ( int j=0 ; j<xsec.size() ; j++ ) { 
      std::cout << "xsec(" << i << ")=" << xsb[i][j] << std::endl;
    } 
  }





  TH1D*  hxsec = g.convolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 

  std::vector<TH1D*>  hxsb(Nsubproc);

  for ( int i=0 ; i<Nsubproc ; i++ ) { 
    hxsb[i] = g.convolute( i, evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 
  }


  hxsec->SetLineColor(kRed);
  hxsec->SetMarkerColor(kRed);
  hxsec->SetMarkerStyle(20);
  hxsec->SetMinimum(0.000001);
  hxsec->DrawCopy();
  gPad->SetLogy(true);
  for ( int i=0 ; i<Nsubproc ; i++ ) { 
    hxsb[i]->SetLineColor(kRed+i%5);
    hxsb[i]->SetMarkerColor(kRed+i%5);
    hxsb[i]->SetLineStyle(1+i%5);
    hxsb[i]->SetMarkerStyle(20+i%5);
    hxsb[i]->DrawCopy("same");
  }


  gPad->Print("xsec.pdf");


  double escale = 7e3/8e3;
  TH1D*  hxsec8 = g.convolute( escale, evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 

  escale = 7e3/2.76e3;
  TH1D*  hxsec276 = g.convolute( escale, evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 


  hxsec->DrawCopy();
  hxsec8->SetLineColor(kRed+1);
  hxsec8->SetLineStyle(2);
  hxsec8->DrawCopy("same");

  gPad->Print("xsec8.pdf");

  hxsec276->SetLineColor(kRed+2);
  hxsec276->SetLineStyle(3);
  hxsec276->DrawCopy("same");

  gPad->Print("xsec276.pdf");

  //  or get into a histogram
  //  TH1D* hxsec = g.convolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 
  //  hxsec->SetName("xsec");

  return 0;
}
```

stand-save.cxx

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "appl_grid/appl_grid.h"
#include "appl_grid/appl_timer.h"

#include "TH1D.h"
#include "TPad.h"


// lhapdf routines
#include "LHAPDF/LHAPDF.h"
extern "C" void evolvepdf_(const double& , const double& , double* ); 
extern "C" double alphaspdf_(const double& Q);



int main(int argc, char** argv) {    

  // use a default atlas inclusive grid
  std::string gridname = "atlas-incljets04-eta1.root";

  if ( argc>1 ) gridname = argv[1];

  std::cout << "reading grid " << gridname << std::endl; 

  // get name of grid from user and create from grid file
  appl::grid g(gridname);

  g.trim(); // trim away uneeded memory

  /// print the grid documentation 
  std::cout << g.getDocumentation() << std::endl;      

  // initialise lhapdf

  std::cout << "setting up lhapdf" << std::endl; 

  // const string _pdfname = "cteq6mE.LHgrid";  
  const string _pdfname = "CT10.LHgrid";  
  int iset = 0;

  LHAPDF::initPDFSet( _pdfname, iset );
  // initpdfset_(_pdfname.c_str());
  // initpdf_( iset );

  // do the convolution into a vector
  std::cout << "doing standalone convolution" << std::endl; 

  //  struct timeval atimer = appl_timer_start(); 

  std::vector<double>  xsec = g.vconvolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 

  //  double atime = appl_timer_stop(atimer); 
  //  std::cout << "time " << atime << " ms" << std::endl;

  for ( int i=0 ; i<xsec.size() ; i++ ) std::cout << "xsec[" << i << "]\t= " << xsec[i] << std::endl;  

  // do the convolution into a TH1D

  //  atimer = appl_timer_start(); 
  TH1D*  hxsec = g.convolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 
  //  atime = appl_timer_stop(atimer); 
  //  std::cout << "time " << atime << " ms" << std::endl;

  hxsec->SetLineColor(kRed);
  hxsec->SetMarkerColor(kRed);
  hxsec->SetMarkerStyle(20);
  hxsec->DrawCopy();
  gPad->SetLogy(true);

  gPad->Print("xsec.pdf");



  return 0;
}
```

stand-tutorial.cxx

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "appl_grid/appl_grid.h"


#include "appl_grid/appl_timer.h"

#include "TH1D.h"
#include "TLatex.h"
#include "TFile.h"
#include "TH2D.h"
#include "TStyle.h"
#include "TCanvas.h"
#include "TPad.h"
#include "TStyle.h"
#include "TColor.h"
#include "TPaveStats.h"


// lhapdf routines
#include "LHAPDF/LHAPDF.h"
extern "C" void evolvepdf_(const double& x, const double& Q, double* xf); 
extern "C" double alphaspdf_(const double& Q);


void setpalette()
{
    const Int_t NRGBs = 7;
    const Int_t NCont = 98;

    Double_t stops[NRGBs] = { 0.00, 0.20, 0.40, 0.60, 0.70, 0.90, 1.00 };

    Double_t red[NRGBs]   = { 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.60, 0.90, 1.00, 0.50 };
    Double_t green[NRGBs] = { 0.00, 0.00, 0.40, 0.95, 1.00, 0.20, 0.00 };
    Double_t blue[NRGBs]  = { 0.00, 1.00, 1.00, 0.10, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00 };

    TColor::CreateGradientColorTable(NRGBs, stops, red, green, blue, NCont);
    gStyle->SetNumberContours(NCont);
}





TH2D* smooth(TH2D* h) { 

  int Nnbins = 10;

  TH2D* hi = new TH2D("h2","", 
              h->GetXaxis()->GetNbins()*Nnbins, 
              h->GetXaxis()->GetBinLowEdge(1), 
              h->GetXaxis()->GetBinLowEdge(h->GetXaxis()->GetNbins()+1), 

              h->GetYaxis()->GetNbins()*Nnbins, 
              h->GetYaxis()->GetBinLowEdge(1), 
              h->GetYaxis()->GetBinLowEdge(h->GetYaxis()->GetNbins()+1) );

  hi->GetXaxis()->SetTitle( h->GetXaxis()->GetTitle() );
  hi->GetYaxis()->SetTitle( h->GetYaxis()->GetTitle() );
  hi->GetYaxis()->SetTitleOffset(1.1);


  for ( int i=1 ; i<=h->GetXaxis()->GetNbins() ; i++ ) { 
    for ( int j=1 ; j<=h->GetYaxis()->GetNbins() ; j++ ) {

      double z1 = h->GetBinContent(i,j);
      double z2 = h->GetBinContent(i+1,j);
      double z3 = h->GetBinContent(i,j+1);
      double z4 = h->GetBinContent(i+1,j+1);


      if ( z2==0 ) z2 = z1;
      if ( z3==0 ) z3 = z1;
      if ( z4==0 ) z4 = z3;

      for ( int ii=0 ; ii<Nnbins ; ii++ ) { 

    double fx = 1.0*ii/Nnbins;

    for ( int jj=0 ; jj<Nnbins ; jj++ ) { 

      double fy = 1.0*jj/Nnbins;

      double z = ( (z4-z3-z2+z1)*fx + z3 - z1 )*fy + (z2-z1)*fx + z1;

      //      std::cout << (i-1)*Nnbins+ii+1 << " " << (j-1)*Nnbins+jj+1 << "\t z : "  << z << "\tz1-4: " << z1 << " " << z2 << " " << z3 << " " << z4 << std::endl; 

      hi->SetBinContent( (i-1)*Nnbins+ii+1, (j-1)*Nnbins+jj+1, z); 
      // hi->SetBinContent( (i-1)*Nnbins+ii+1, (j-1)*Nnbins+jj+1, h->GetBinContent(i,j) ); 

    }

      } 
    }

  }

  return hi;

}









int main(int argc, char** argv) { 

  gStyle->SetOptStat(0);

  setpalette();

  // use a default atlas inclusive grid
  std::string gridname = "atlas-incljets-arxiv-1009.5908v2/r04/atlas-incljets-eta1.root";

  if ( argc>1 ) gridname = argv[1];

  std::cout << "reading grid " << gridname << std::endl; 

  appl::grid g(gridname);
  //  g.trim(); // trim away uneeded memory

  /// print the grid documentation 
  std::cout << g.getDocumentation() << std::endl; 


  // initialise lhapdf

  std::cout << "setting up lhapdf" << std::endl; 

  //  const std::string _pdfname = "cteq6mE.LHgrid";  
  const std::string _pdfname = "CT10.LHgrid";  
  int iset = 0;

  LHAPDF::initPDFSet( _pdfname, iset );
  // initpdfset_(_pdfname.c_str());
  // initpdf_( iset );



  ///  ----------------- example 1 -------------------- 

  if ( true ) { 

    // do the convolution into a vector
    std::cout << "example 1: standalone convolution" << std::endl; 

    struct timeval atimer = appl_timer_start(); 

    std::vector<double>  xsec = g.vconvolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 

    double atime = appl_timer_stop(atimer); 

    std::cout << "time : " << atime << " ms" << std::endl;

    for ( int i=0 ; i<xsec.size() ; i++ ) std::cout << "xsec[" << i << "]\t= " << xsec[i] << std::endl;  

    TH1D*  hxsec = g.convolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 

    hxsec->SetTitle("");
    hxsec->DrawCopy();

    gPad->SetLogy(true);
    gPad->Print("example-1.pdf");

  }


  ///  ----------------- example 2 (corrections) -------------------- 

  if ( false ) { 

    std::cout << "example 2: multiplicative corrections" << std::endl; 

    std::cout << g.getApplyCorrections() << std::endl;

    g.setApplyCorrections(false);
    TH1D*  huncor = g.convolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 

    g.setApplyCorrections(true);
    TH1D*  hcor = g.convolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 

    huncor->SetLineStyle(2);
    huncor->SetTitle("");

    huncor->DrawCopy();
    hcor->DrawCopy("same");

    gPad->Print("example-2.pdf");

  }

  ///  ----------------- example 3 (cms scaling) -------------------- 

  if ( false ) { 

    std::cout << "example 3: centre-of-mass energy scaling " << std::endl;

    TH1D* h7 = g.convolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 

    double Escale = 7/2.46;

    TH1D* h246 = g.convolute( Escale, evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ ); 

    std::cout << "cms scale " << g.getCMSScale() << std::endl;

    h7->SetTitle("");
    h7->SetMinimum(0.001);

    gStyle->SetOptStat(0);

    h7->DrawCopy();
    h246->SetLineColor(kRed);
    h246->DrawCopy("same");

    gPad->SetLogy(true);
    gPad->Print("example-3.pdf");

  }





  ///  ------------------ example 4 (scale variation) -----------------

  if ( false ) {

    std::cout << "example 4: scale variation " << std::endl;

    int nloops = 1; // loop order

    int Nbins = 30;
    TH2D* hscale = new TH2D("scale", "", Nbins, 0.45, 2.05,  Nbins, 0.45, 2.05 );

    struct timeval atimer = appl_timer_start(); 

    for ( int i=1 ; i<=hscale->GetNbinsX() ; i++ ) { 
      double fscale = hscale->GetXaxis()->GetBinCenter(i); 

      for ( int j=1 ; j<=hscale->GetNbinsY() ; j++ ) { 
    double rscale = hscale->GetYaxis()->GetBinCenter(j);

    std::vector<double> xs = g.vconvolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_, nloops, rscale, fscale );

    double total = 0;
    for ( int k=xs.size() ; k-- ; ) total += xs[k];

    hscale->Fill( fscale, rscale, total );

      }
    }  

    double atime = appl_timer_stop(atimer);

    std::cout << "time " << atime << " ms" << std::endl;


    /// plot ....


    gStyle->SetPalette(52);
    gStyle->SetPadRightMargin(0.17);


    TCanvas* tc = new TCanvas( "","", 650, 600 );

    hscale->GetXaxis()->SetTitle("factorisation scale factor");
    hscale->GetYaxis()->SetTitle("renormalisation scale factor");
    hscale->GetYaxis()->SetTitleOffset(1.1);

    TH2D* _hscale = smooth(hscale);

    _hscale->DrawCopy("colz");

    gPad->Print("example-4.png");


    TFile fs("scale.root","recreate");
    fs.cd();
    hscale->Write();
    fs.Write();
    fs.Close();

  }



  ///  ------------------ example 5 (subprocesses) -----------------

  if ( false ) {

    std::cout << "example 4: subprocess contributions " << std::endl;

    std::vector<double> xsec = g.vconvolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_);

    std::vector<TH1D*> xsec_sub(g.subProcesses());

    for ( int i=0 ; i<g.subProcesses() ; i++ ) {
      xsec_sub[i] = g.convolute_subproc( i, evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_);

      for ( int j=0 ; j<xsec_sub[i]->GetNbinsX() ; j++ ) { 
    xsec_sub[i]->SetBinContent( j+1,  xsec_sub[i]->GetBinContent(j+1)/xsec[j] );
      }
    }


    /// plot ...

    int col[7] = { kRed, kBlue, kMagenta, kCyan, kGreen, kBlack, kViolet };

    xsec_sub[0]->SetMaximum(0.6);
    xsec_sub[0]->SetMinimum(0);
    xsec_sub[0]->GetXaxis()->SetTitle("P_{T} [GeV]");
    xsec_sub[0]->GetYaxis()->SetTitle("subprocess fraction");
    xsec_sub[0]->SetTitle("");


    xsec_sub[0]->DrawCopy();


    for ( int i=0 ; i<g.subProcesses() ; i++ ) {
      xsec_sub[i]->SetLineColor(col[i]);
      xsec_sub[i]->DrawCopy("same");

      TLatex* tl = new TLatex(0,0,"");
      tl->SetTextColor(col[i]);
      tl->SetTextSize(0.04);

      char label[64];
      sprintf(label, "subprocess %d", i);

      tl->DrawLatex(430, 0.55-0.035*i, label );
    }

    gPad->SetLogy(false);

    gPad->Print("example-5.pdf");

  }




  ///   -------------------- example 6 (pdf sets) -----------------------

  if ( false ) {

    // const std::string _pdfname = "cteq6mE.LHgrid";  
    const std::string _pdfname = "CT10.LHgrid";  
    int iset = 0;

    LHAPDF::initPDFSet( _pdfname, iset );
    std::vector<double> _xs = g.vconvolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ );

    int Nset = LHAPDF::numberPDF();

    std::vector<TH1D*> xs(Nset); 

    for ( int i=0 ; i<Nset ; i++ ) {
      struct timeval atimer = appl_timer_start();
      LHAPDF::initPDFSet( _pdfname, i );
      double atime = appl_timer_stop(atimer);
      std::cout << "set " << i << "\tinitPDF time " << atime << " ms" << std::endl;

      atimer = appl_timer_start();
      xs[i] = g.convolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ );
      atime = appl_timer_stop(atimer);

      std::cout << "convolution time " << atime << " ms" << std::endl;

      for ( int j=_xs.size() ; j-- ; ) xs[i]->SetBinContent( j+1, xs[i]->GetBinContent(j+1)/_xs[j]);   
    }

    xs[0]->SetMaximum(1.1);
    xs[0]->SetMinimum(0.9);
    gPad->SetLogy(false);
    gPad->SetLogx(true);

    xs[0]->DrawCopy("l");
    for ( int i=0 ; i<Nset ; i++ ) xs[i]->DrawCopy("lsame");

    gPad->Print("example-6.pdf");
    gPad->SetLogx(false);
  }


  /// ------------------- example 7 (timers) ---------------------

  if ( false ) {

    gStyle->SetOptStat(2220);

    std::cout << "example 7 : timings" << std::endl;

    TH1D* htrim   = new TH1D("htrim",   "", 100, 38, 45);
    // TH1D* htrim2  = new TH1D("htrim2",  "", 100, 37, 45);
    TH1D* huntrim = new TH1D("huntrim", "", 100, 38, 45);


    g.trim();

    std::cout << "grid size : " << g.size() << std::endl;

    for ( int i=400 ; i-- ; ) { 
      struct timeval atimer = appl_timer_start();
      std::vector<double> xsec = g.vconvolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ );
      double atime = appl_timer_stop( atimer );
      htrim->Fill(atime);
    }

     g.untrim();

    std::cout << "grid size : " << g.size() << std::endl;

    for ( int i=400 ; i-- ; ) { 
      struct timeval atimer = appl_timer_start();
      std::vector<double> xsec = g.vconvolute( evolvepdf_, alphaspdf_ );
      double atime = appl_timer_stop( atimer );
      huntrim->Fill(atime);
    }


    if ( huntrim->GetMaximum()<htrim->GetMaximum() ) huntrim->SetMaximum(1.1*htrim->GetMaximum());
    else                                             htrim->SetMaximum(1.1*huntrim->GetMaximum());
    huntrim->SetLineStyle(2);
    huntrim->SetLineColor(kRed);
    htrim->GetXaxis()->SetTitle("time [ms]");
    huntrim->GetXaxis()->SetTitle("time [ms]");

    huntrim->Draw();
    htrim->Draw("same");
    //  htrim2->DrawCopy("same");
    huntrim->Draw("same");
    htrim->Draw("sames+");
    huntrim->Draw("sames+");

    gPad->Update();

    TPaveStats* tp1 = (TPaveStats*)htrim->GetListOfFunctions()->FindObject("stats");
    TPaveStats* tp2 = (TPaveStats*)huntrim->GetListOfFunctions()->FindObject("stats");

    std::cout << tp1 << " " << tp2 << std::endl;

    tp2->SetTextColor(kRed);


    tp1->SetY1NDC(0.93-0.15);
    tp1->SetY2NDC(0.93);

    tp2->SetY1NDC(0.93-0.16-0.15);
    tp2->SetY2NDC(0.93-0.16);

    tp1->Draw();
    tp2->Draw();

    gPad->Update();

    gPad->Print("example-7.pdf");

  }

  return 0;
}
```

any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When ask about problems in the particular code, add this code into the question post itself instead of providing link to it. This is explicitely stated in the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page.

Comment: Thank you, the example code is made by different files, that is why I provided a link, I'll add it ASAP

Comment: can you also post the error message from the linker you're getting? I see you wrote it's an undefined reference, but undefined reference to what?